# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X|>n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to show that if $X \in L^1$, where $X$ is a real-valued random variable, the sum

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X|>n)$

converges absolute.

My idea was the following:

Since $X \in L^1$, I have

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot \mathbb{P}(|X|=n)~< \infty$.

So I get:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X|>n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X|=k) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(|X|=n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot \mathbb{P}(|X|=n)~<\infty$

This would only hold if $X$ could only attain natural numbers; how can I generalize this to show that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X|>n)$

converges absolute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integrate both sides of the "positive" pointwise inequality $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{|X|\geqslant n}\leqslant |X|.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I've got it now :)

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1267610/